# Running .jl file from R or Python

Tags: python, r, julia

I am new to Julia. I developed a few lines of code to get the results I needed from packages I was not able to find in Python or R. Now, I am trying to get this file to be easily accessible, and wrap the code in Python or R. Has anyone done this before? I have tried a few methods and have not found anything that has helped.

The most simple way to do this would be just a few lines of code that calls the .jl file, runs it (which the code is then added to a .txt file from julia), and then alerts you when the code is done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. R is the preferable method and at this point Python would be appreciated as well.

Comment: See the package JuliaCall: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JuliaCall/index.html

Comment: if you have a complete julia script that can be run and produce output on a drive, then you can simply make a `system` call from R or python, calling the julia interpreter on that julia script.

Comment: And there is PyJulia for python: https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: @nicola can you give me example R code for how to call the .jl file?

Comment: Thomas:   `system("your_command_line  goes_here")`

Comment: this seems to be executing very slow in Python, and giving me the wrong answer in R. Any tips?

Comment: When you follow my answer the Julia package will get pre-compiled in the first run and subsequent runs will be faster. The start-up speed can be further increased by fully compiling the package into Julia system image.

Answer (score 4):

Please find below instructions for Python, R and just an external process (which of course is an executable command that can be run from any other process). I recommend putting your code in a package and loading it in one of those languages rather than executing this as an external process.

### Python

1. Use Python Anaconda (not in-built system Python) and install Julia
2. Run Julia and install `PyCall`

   ```
   using Pkg
   ENV["PYTHON"]="/path/to/your/python/executable"
   pkg"add PyCall"
   pkg"build PyCall"
   ```
3. Put your code into a Julia package

   ```
   using Pkg
   Pkg.generate("MyPackage")
   ```

   In the folder `src` you will find `MyPackage.jl`, edit it to look like this:

   ```
   module MyPackage
   function main(x,y)
        #do very complex staff or place it in your_other_file.jl
        2x.+y
   end
   include("your_other_file.jl")
   export main, and_whatever_other_functio_you_defined
   end
   ```
4. Install pyjulia

   ```
   python -m pip install julia
   ```

   (On Linux systems you might want to use `python3` instead of `python` command)

   For this step note that while an external Python can be used with Julia. However, for a convenience it might be worth
   to consider using a Python that got installed together with Julia as `PyCall`.
   In that case for installation use a command such this one:

   ```
   %HOMEPATH%\.julia\conda\3\python -m pip install julia
   ```

   or on Linux

   ```
   ~/.julia/conda/3/python -m pip install julia
   ```

   Note that if you have `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` variable defined you can replace `%HOMEPATH%\.julia` or `~/.julia/` with its value.
5. Run the appropiate Python and tell it to configure the Python-Julia integration:

   ```py
   import julia
   julia.install()
   ```
6. Now you are ready to call your Julia code:

   ```
   >>> from julia import Pkg
   >>> Pkg.activate(".\\MyPackage") #use the correct path
       Activating environment at `MyPackage\Project.toml`
   >>> from julia import MyPackage
   >>> MyPackage.main([1,2],5)
       [7,9]
   ```

### Gnu R

1. Configure your system `PATH` variable to point to your Julia location. Hence when you type `julia` in the console it should start Julia
2. Run the script below to install R-Julia integration

```
install.packages("JuliaCall")

library(JuliaCall)
julia <- julia_setup()
```

3. Follow the above instructions for Python (step 3 only) and create the package named `MyPackage`
4. Run the code

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia_eval("using Pkg;Pkg.activate(\"C:/temp/rrr/MyPackage\")")
julia_library("MyPackage")

julia_eval("MyPackage.main(3,5)")
```

### Bash (or just any language)

1. Build the package following instructions for Python (step 3 only)
2. Configure the system `PATH` variable
3. Being in the package directory run the command (note `string(:.)` is a Julian trick that I use to avoid apostrophe escaping in bash commands):

```
julia -e "using Pkg;Pkg.activate(string(:.));Pkg.instantiate();using MyPackage;MyPackage.main(3,4)"
```

This will install all dependencies for your package. In order to skip the installation remove `Pkg.instantiate()` from the above command.

Comment: Can you clarify: if not running any Python code, can `R` execute the `Julia` commands and `.jl` files without the need for  `python` or  `anaconda` ?

Comment: You do not need Python. The reference was only to the point 3 of Python instructions -> explanation how to put your Julia code into the package. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @przemyslaw-szufel is correct but maybe a bit overcomplicated. You don't necessarily need to wrap your code in a module or define a custom environment (yes it is good practice, but a step at the time...)

First create a file `juliaScripts.jl` with content:

```
function getAnElement(array,n)
    return array[n]
end
```

### To run functions defined in a .jl file in R

Then in R you just do:

```
> install.packages("JuliaCall")
> library(JuliaCall)
> julia_setup() # on every new R session !
> julia_source("juliaScript.jl")
> out <- julia_call("getAnElement",c(10,20,30),2)
> out
[1] 20
```

Note that the R vector has been automatically converted to a Julia Array.

### To run functions defined in a .jl file in Python

In Python, it is even easier:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user julia
>>> import julia
>>> julia.install() # only once, not every session
>>> jl=julia.Julia(compiled_modules=False)
>>> from julia import Main
>>> Main.include("juliaScript.jl")
>>> Main.getAnElement([1,2,3],2)
20
```

Also in Python arrays (native python lists as well Numpy arrays and other commonly used data structures) are automatically converted between Python and Julia.

Not to make advertising, but more details on interfacing R <-> Julia or Python <-> Julia are on my Apress(2019) book "Julia Quick Syntax reference" in Chapter 7 "Interfacing Julia with other languages" (I shouldn't say it, but you can easily find the pdf online in well-known sites...)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [JuliaConnectoR package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=JuliaConnectoR):

```r
library(JuliaConnectoR)
fun <- juliaCall("include", "/path/to/file.jl") # you may need to provide the full path
```

For more info on JuliaConnectoR, see the link above as well as [this paper](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v101.i06), which additionally compares it to alternative packages suck as JuliaCall and XRJulia.