# How to run a jl file (julia) in R

Tags: r, julia

I know that the  JuliaCall package allows to us use the Julia language in R. But I have a jl script with complex instructions and I would like to run in the R language!
For example, suposse that my jl file is "myscript.jl" return a certain array A.

```
#install.packages("JuliaCall")
library(JuliaCall)
```

Is there some function to run the jl file?

```
A <- somefunction("myscript.jl")
```

some help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running .jl file from R or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077761/running-jl-file-from-r-or-python)

Comment: it's a good solution, although I thought it was simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed quite simple if you have Julia on path.

First create a file `juliaScripts.jl` with content:

```
function getAnElement(array,n)
    return array[n]
end
```

Then in R you just do:

```
> install.packages("JuliaCall")
> library(JuliaCall)
> julia_setup() # on every new R session !
> julia_source("juliaScript.jl")
> out <- julia_call("getAnElement",c(10,20,30),2)
> out
[1] 20
```

Note that the R vector has been automatically converted to a Julia Array.

Not to make advertising, but more details on interfacing R <-> Julia are on my Apress(2019) book "Julia Quick Syntax reference" on Chapter 7 "Interfacing Julia with other languages" (I shouldn't say it, but you can easily find the pdf online in well-known sites...)

Comment: It is a better possible solution, but I get the erros on '''> julia_setup() # on every new R session !''' Error in julia_setup() : Julia is not found. I try to do julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "the folder that contains julia binary") but I don't know how to find the folder that contais julia binary.

Comment: If you are able to start Julia, start it and then type `Sys.BINDIR`. The output will be the folder containing the julia executable, e.g. `"/usr/lib/julia/julia-1.6.1/bin"`